# wp_remote_post with ssl:// protocol

Tags: functions, remote, http-api

```
    $response = wp_remote_post( 'ssl://securesite.com', array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'body' => $string, // variable is set
        'timeout' => apply_filters( 'http_request_timeout', 15),
        'sslverify' => true
    ));

    error_log(print_r($response, TRUE));

    if ( is_wp_error($response) ) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $result = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
```

The result is an error:

```
[30-Aug-2011 21:53:53] WP_Error Object
(
[errors] => Array
    (
        [http_request_failed] => Array
            (
                [0] => Unsupported protocol: ssl
            )

    )

[error_data] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

If I use fsockopen and fgets everything works fine.

Seems like I'm missing an undocumented trick since ssl should be handled by wp_remote_post.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be error coming from WP itself, but is likely generated by curl, which WP likes to pick first for network requests.

I'd try to replicate request with curl by hand on your hosting and elsewhere.

If you are content with doing network request in other way you can tweak to make WP skip curl as transport and go for other options.

Comment: Do you know what filter I should be using to skip curl for this instance of wp_remote_post without skipping curl for all the other http posts?

Comment: @Dan Cameron I usually use must-have [Core Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/) plugin for debugging network transport issues.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get "ssl://" as being a valid protocol from?

Did you try it with "https://" instead?